# Is it a common behaviour in insects to mate with a dead partner

Tags: entomology, lepidoptera

I have a few specimens of *Orgyia antiqua* of both sexes, and I've been able to observe a mating behaviour where male and female sit close to each other, their rear ends connected.

Today though I've seen the same, but the female was day-long dead - and that didn't stop the male from the mating attempt.

I do understand that it can be explained with the male just reacting to some pheromones, still present on the female body, but that is a bit weird anyway.

Thus the question. **Is it a common or well-known behaviour for an insect male to mate with a dead female?**